# Python: Following different paths depending on answer using functions

Tags: python

I am working on a piece of code which asks the user several yes/no questions; depending on the answer a different path should be followed, some paths could lead to another question, and others to an answer.

I have coded this in Python with many embedded if, elif and else statements, but I was looking for a more efficient method using functions.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can use a function to:

- Ask the question
- Check if the answer is Yes/No
- Follow to either ask another question or given an answer depending.

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like questions and answers may be objects, arbitrary linked through references and probably initialized from a text file. Which reference is followed depends on the answer. So a kind of "state machine". To ask  your questions you'd need the "visitor pattern". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 3):

You can try encoding the question/answer path in a graph-like data structure.

Here's an example of what I mean (`qa.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


# I've made them strings for now but they can be anything you want
# For e.g. Django question models
questions = [
    'Question 1',
    'Question 2',
    'Question 3',
    'Question 4',
    'Question 5',
]


# Similarly these can be anything you want
answers = [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3',
    'Answer 4',
]


# The idea is to have a collection of questions and a collection of answers
# Then, we wire them up in a graph-like structure


class Node(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass

class QuestionNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, question, yes_node, no_node):
        self.question = question
        self.yes_node = yes_node
        self.no_node = no_node

    def run(self):
        print(self.question)

        # Basic prompt for illustration purposes only
        answer = None
        while answer not in ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no']:
            answer = input('(y/n) > ').lower()

        if answer[0] == 'y':
            self.yes_node.run()
        else:
            self.no_node.run()


class AnswerNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, answer):
        self.answer = answer

    def run(self):
        print('Answer: ' + self.answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    answer_nodes = [AnswerNode(answer) for answer in answers]

    q4 = QuestionNode(questions[4], answer_nodes[1], answer_nodes[2])
    q3 = QuestionNode(questions[3], answer_nodes[0], q4)
    q2 = QuestionNode(questions[2], answer_nodes[2], answer_nodes[3])
    q1 = QuestionNode(questions[1], answer_nodes[0], q3)
    q0 = QuestionNode(questions[0], q1, q2)

    q0.run()
```

And, here's the output for this configuration (I've illustrated all possible paths):

```
$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > y
Question 2
(y/n) > y
Answer: Answer 1

$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > y
Question 2
(y/n) > n
Question 4
(y/n) > y
Answer: Answer 1

$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > y
Question 2
(y/n) > n
Question 4
(y/n) > n
Question 5
(y/n) > y
Answer: Answer 2

$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > y
Question 2
(y/n) > n
Question 4
(y/n) > n
Question 5
(y/n) > n
Answer: Answer 3

$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > n
Question 3
(y/n) > y
Answer: Answer 3

$ ./qa.py 
Question 1
(y/n) > n
Question 3
(y/n) > n
Answer: Answer 4
```

Notice that I separated the questions and answers from the graph structure. This is deliberate in order to allow for the greatest flexibility. This means it's easier for the same question/answer to appear multiple times but along different paths in the graph.

**P.S.:** *This reminded me of the [Jellyvision](http://www.jellyvision.com/) products I came across long time ago.*